# setState without async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть работающий метод

```
handleChange = (event, props)=>{
    const match = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(this.state.value, 'i'));
    const foundedPlaces = this.state.foundedPlaces.filter((place)=>match.test(place.name));
    this.setState({
        value : event.target.value.substr(0,20),
        foundedPlaces: foundedPlaces.sort(sortBy('name'))
    });
    console.log(this.state.foundedPlaces)
    this.props.getPlaces(this.state.foundedPlaces);
}
```

но стейт обновляется асинхронно и при передаче данных несколько запаздывает. Value  передается из другого компонента, а foundedPlaces это отсортированный массив, как лучше переписать

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({authorFlickr: authorPics});
});
```

увы, не работает(( и кстати этот метод тоже надо переписать на синк

Comment: А зачем это вообще класть в state?

Comment: это передается в родительский компонент, нижний метод, данные в дидМаунт идут (не видны в скоупе)

Comment: чтобы понимать, одни данные локальные, а вторые из другого компонента

Answer (score 1):

Вторым параметром у setState идет callback, срабатывающий после изменения состояния, чтобы гарантированно получить новые данные

```
this.setState({
    value : event.target.value.substr(0,20),
    foundedPlaces: foundedPlaces.sort(sortBy('name'))
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.foundedPlaces);
    this.props.getPlaces(this.state.foundedPlaces);
});
```